# How to detect client's connection alive from gRPC server side

Tags: c#, server, grpc

I am working at client-server architecture project in which client side is programmed by swiftUI, server side is programmed by C#, and communication between two sides use gRPC protocol.

I need to monitor client connection status from server side, when it's status become offline(or disconnection). I should do something for that client in server side. So my question is how to detect client connection alive from server side.

For example.

Client Side.      |     Server Side.

```
`Client A.--------> MyServer_grpcMethod1`  
`Client B.----XX--> MyServer_grpcMethod2`  
`Client C.--------> MyServer_grpcMethod3`
```

In above example, when client B become disconnected with MyServer. In MyServer, which way will be used to detected it.

note: I tried to set a timeout in server side. but it didn't work as I expected.